# How to use "compileOnSave" in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Typescript has a configuration option for auto compilation of typescript, [as documented here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig.json.html).

```
{
   "compileOnSave": true,
   "compilerOptions": {
       "noImplicitAny" : true
   }
}
```

But simply including this in my tsconfig.json file is not enough to trigger auto compilation. I use MS Visual Studio Code as my IDE.
How do I trigger the "compile on save" behavior?

Comment: As of 2023, the official [TSConfig Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) page no-longer mentions `compileOnSave` at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [TypeScript site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig.json.html):

"This feature is currently supported in Visual Studio 2015 with TypeScript 1.8.4 and above, and atom-typescript plugin."

So, it isn't supported by Visual Studio Code at this time. I use this option at work with Visual Studio 2015 and at home with Atom and it works fine. This is actually one of the reasons I switched from Visual Studio Code to Atom.

Comment: Ah, again the confusion between VS and VS Code. But why switch to atom? You can simply add -w to the tsc command to autocompile, right?

Comment: Yes, but that was too slow for me. It would take 10 or 15 seconds to compile sometimes and I would have already launched the page with the old code wondering why my change didn't seem to work. A gulp watcher task was fast, but I would constantly forget to start the process before I started coding. Also, once I tried Atom, I just liked the look and feel more.

Answer (score 4):

Try watch parameter at compilerOptions...
It will be monitoring changes in your ts files and be automatically refresh in your js files. Example:

```js
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module":"commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outDir": "Scripts/javascript",
        "watch": true,
        "sourceMap": true       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Atom IDE version - 1.34.0 running on windows 10 x64 system.

The issue was fixed after installing missing packages `atom-ide-ui` and `atom-typescript`.

Here is how my **tsconfig.json** file looks like.

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

> I have TypeScript version 3.2.4 installed globally.